# How to use Twitter-Userstream on iOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, twitter

I edited `TWRequest` sample code for userstream. But parsing does not start.
Do we use `performRequestWithHandler:` for userstream?

```
NSURL* url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://userstream.twitter.com/2/user.json"];
TWRequest* timeline = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];
timeline.account = _account; // ACAccount

[timeline performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData* responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse, NSError* error) {
    NSError* jsonError = nil;
    id data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObject:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&jsonError];

  //  ...(Status Parse)

}];
```